# How to parametizer multibranch job - Jenkins cURL

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to build a multibranch project with parameters. This is my `input` stage:

[image]

So, the cURL command that I use is the following:

`curl -X POST "JENKINS_URL/job/PROJECT_NAME/job/BRANCH_NAME/build" --user "MY_JENKINS_USER:MY_JENKINS_TOKEN" -d json='{"parameter": {"name": "backend", "value": true}, {"name": "frontend", "value": true} }'`

It only build the Jenkins job but the Jenkins console is waiting to input the parameters...

[image]

Probably I missing some parameter in the cURL command that I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah well, you have an input around this. I would recommend to move your parameters to the top of the pipeline like in the example below, so your trigger will work as expected. Otherwise you need a separate call to answer the input.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'PERSON', defaultValue: 'Mr Jenkins', description: 'Who should I say hello to?')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "Hello ${params.PERSON}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, finally I did that and I was going to update my question but you answered before! ahaha x) Anyway, I will put your answer as the solution to my question, thank you so much!